# DTExec reporting only Data Flow task

Tags: logging, cmd, ssis, windows-task-scheduler, dtexec

In Windows 7 I want to schedule the execution of some DTSX packages. What I've done is to make a CMD file for each DTSX package, and schedule them with Windows Scheduler.

Starting from [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/445172/Fetching-Progress-tab-result-in-text-file-in-SSIS#answer3), **I write the following code for my CMD files**:

```
@ECHO ON
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /FILE "C:\MyPath\MyPackage.dtsx" /REP P > "C:\MyPath\MyPackage.txt"
```

the problem is that in the log saved to the file `C:\MyPath\MyPackage.txt` I can see only the progress of **Data Flow** tasks.

How can I write the progress of all the flow items (for example "Script Tasks", "Execute SQL tasks", ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress information is received from **On Progress** events, which are available on DataFlow tasks only. **On Progress** event is fired when complete buffer is processed or at the end of processed data flow.
Regular Tasks do not have **On Progress** event, since they are not processing lines of data; they are either at *Completed* or *Failed* state. So, you cannot see progress of standard non-DataFlow tasks at your log.

Answer (score 1):

/Rep P indicates to report On Progress events, which would be related to the data flow.  To see more detailed information use 'V' for Verbose:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /FILE "C:\MyPath\MyPackage.dtsx" /REP **V** > "C:\MyPath\MyPackage.txt"

For more options, look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility